# Email recipients based on Shipping method Id for Woocommerce new order notification

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

In Woocommerce, I would like to have a new order email sent to specific persons based on the selected shipping method ID.

Right now, I am only able to have every email address added to the new order email, but ultimately want to have the email be sent to one specific email based on the shipping method Id selected by the customer.

Here is my code [coming from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26429482/woocommerce-need-to-send-email-to-specific-address-based-on-zip-code/26434114#26434114) that works for postal code:

```
add_filter( 'new_order' , 'so_26429482_add_recipient', 20, 2 );

function so_26429482_add_recipient( $email, $order ) {
    $additional_email = "somebody@somewhere.net";
    if( $order->shipping_postcode == "90210" ){
        $email = explode( ',', $email );
        array_push( $email, $additional_email );
    }
    return $email;
}
```

**Instead I should need to target the shipping method Id**.

My two shipping methods Ids are `flat_rate:8` and `flat_rate:9`.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Hello and welcome! _"Does anyone know how to do this?"_ Probably, but please share what _you_ [have tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 2** - Your code is outdated as `new_order` hook doesn't exist anymore *(still works on WooCommerce version 8+)*

Is not possible to remove the default email set in new order email notification. But we can add additional email recipient to new order email notification conditionally based on the order shipping method Id:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'new_order_additional_recipients', 20, 2 );
function new_order_additional_recipients( $recipient, $order ) {
    if ( ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) return $recipient;

    // Set Below your email adresses
    $email1 = 'name1@domain.com';
    $email2 = 'name2@domain.com';

    // Get the shipping method Id
    $shipping_items = $order->get_items('shipping');
    $shipping_item  = reset($shipping_items);
    $shipping_method_id  = $shipping_item->get_method_id() . ':';
    $shipping_method_id .= $shipping_item->get_instance_id();

    // Adding recipients conditionally
    if ( 'flat_rate:8' == $shipping_method_id )
        $recipient .= ',' . $email1;
    elseif ( 'flat_rate:9' == $shipping_method_id )
        $recipient .= ',' . $email2;

    return $recipient;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.

Comment: The zone names are flat_rate:8 and flat_rate:9, where in your example do I put that?

Comment: My apologies, thats what I meant.  The shipping methods are flat_rate:8 and flat_rate:9.

Comment: I am getting an internal server error on that one... thoughts?