# Trigger an email notification to a specific email based off order processing and shipping method id

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications, shipping-method

I am trying to send an additional email notification to one of our locations for delivery, based off the shipping method ID. I found [this answer code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51768624/email-recipients-based-on-shipping-method-id-for-woocommerce-new-order-notificat/51770788#51770788), but I am not able to change it in the correct way, to make it work with my shipping methods:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'new_order_additional_recipients', 20, 2 );
function new_order_additional_recipients( $recipient, $order ) {
    if ( ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) return $recipient;

    // Set Below your email adresses
    $email1 = 'name1@domain.com';
    $email2 = 'name2@domain.com';

    // Get the shipping method Id
    $shipping_items = $order->get_items('shipping');
    $shipping_item  = reset($shipping_items);
    $shipping_method_id  = $shipping_item->get_method_id() . ':';
    $shipping_method_id .= $shipping_item->get_instance_id();

    // Adding recipients conditionally
    if ( 'flat_rate:8' == $shipping_method_id )
        $recipient .= ',' . $email1;
    elseif ( 'flat_rate:9' == $shipping_method_id )
        $recipient .= ',' . $email2;

    return $recipient;
}
```

This is what I tried to use and for some reason I get no email sent to the recipients based on the method ID. Do I need to add order processing into the code for this to trigger? maybe something like this:

```
if('customer_processing_order' !=$email_id );
if('flat_rate:8' == $shipping_method_id );
```

I will be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The code works, so you are not getting the right slugs… Now as each shipping instance ID is unique, you can try the following:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'new_order_additional_recipients', 20, 2 );
function new_order_additional_recipients( $recipient, $order ) {
    if ( ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) return $recipient;

    // Set Below your email adresses
    $email1 = 'name1@domain.com';
    $email2 = 'name2@domain.com';

    // Get the shipping method Id
    $shipping_items = $order->get_items('shipping');
    $shipping_item  = reset($shipping_items);

    // Adding recipients conditionally
    if ( $shipping_item->get_instance_id() == 8 ){
        $recipient .= ',' . $email1;
    } elseif( $shipping_item->get_instance_id() == 9 ){
        $recipient .= ',' . $email2;
    }
    return $recipient;
}
```

It should work

---

To retrieve the correct shipping method identifiers, you can use the following, that will display in frontend footer, only for admins, all the shipping method identifiers *(you may need to add some products to cart)*:

```php
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_footer_test_output', 10);
function wp_footer_test_output() {
    if( current_user_can('administrator') ) {
        echo '<pre>'. print_r( WC()->session->get('shipping_for_package_0')['rates'], true ) . '</pre>';
    }
}
```

Now that you get the shipping method Identifiers, you can remove that code.

Comment: Question: Am I only adding in the   [instance_id] => 30 to where the 8 & 9 are located in the code? Or do I also update the area  $shipping_items = $order->get_items('shipping'); to include [id] => szbd-shipping-method:30 as such:  $shipping_items = $order->get_items('szbd-shipping-method:30');

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. Maybe I need to add the 'shipping' as 'szbd-shipping-method:30'?

Comment: // Adding recipients conditionally
    if ( $shipping_item->get_instance_id() == 30 ){
        $recipient .= ',' . $email1;
    } elseif( $shipping_item->get_instance_id() == 30 ){
        $recipient .= ',' . $email2;
    }
    return $recipient;

Comment: As an edit in your question, could you please add the raw output that my last function do when you use it, and notify me here… Then I will be able to update my code for it.

Comment: Array
( [szbd-shipping-method:30] => WC_Shipping_Rate Object
        (     [data:protected] => Array
                (    [id] => szbd-shipping-method:30
                    [method_id] => szbd-shipping-method
                    [instance_id] => 30
                    [label] => Chattanooga Local Delivery
                    [cost] => 10.00
                    [taxes] => Array
                        (        )     )
            [meta_data:protected] => Array
                (     [Items] => Top Shelf THCa Flower Pre-Roll – Craft Cannabis™ - Gas O.G. × 1    )  )

Comment: This is the shipping method identifier that was displayed on the frontend footer - the other shipping method is USPS that I did not include since I couldn't comment the whole array. Please let me know if you need anything else. Thanks for your help